# Magento Multistore possible for this?

Tags: multistore, currency, ce-1.9.2.2

I want to make a multistore and already made the 3 different websites, stores and for every store 3 storeviews for languages.
the first shop is the german standard shop with 19% tax.
the second shop should be an austrian shop with 20% tax.
the third shop should be a swiss shop with CHF (Swiss Franks) as currency.
First of all, is this possible? And then how?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes it's possible.
Longer answer:
You can assign taxes per website so you can have a difference between DE an AT shops.
You can also have different currencies for websites.
And here you have 2 options.
You either enter the prices in EUR for your first 2 shops, enable CHF for the CH website and set an conversion rate.
Then for the CH website the prices will be automatically changed.
The second option is to change the price scope from system->configuration->catalog to `Website` and manage different prices for the CH website.
In this case you need to set the base currency for the CH website to CHF. You can do that from system->configuration->currency setup (I think).